# Google App Script loop multiple web page to scrape data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have try to use
`=ImportXML("https://spiderum.com/s/all/hot?page=1","//a[@class='username']")`
in Google spreadsheet to scrape text value. But the website is have multiple page (1,2,3,4...n).

So there has some way to create a script int Google App Script to loop over all page of this website and collect all value needed to show in spreadsheet?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the detail result you want, when you want to retrieve HTML data from several URLs using Google Apps Script, for example, how about using [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)?

Comment: Why do you want a script? Put this formula `=ImportXML("https://spiderum.com/s/all/hot?page="&N4,"//a[@class='username']"` in a cell where cell N4 contains the "page number", then the formula across the page and insert new page numbers in row N. Then highlight the whole thing, Copy/Paste Special/Paste Values Only, and you're done.